# MySQL Help with Desktop Based Administration

Tags: mysql, best-practices

I am making a MySQL based database for a professor and she would like to have a version uploaded to the web and a version on her desktop for personal use.  The web version would be "official" whereas the one on her desktop would be used for personal research and would have additional categories, etc.  The two databases do not have to be linked but I was unsure if it would be easier to put both databases on the web and make her personal one password protected or if there was a good desktop based program.  She is not very tech-savvy which is why I was leaning away from having her install MySQL and Apache on her own desktop.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a very small database, I recommend using [**XEROUND free database service**](http://xeround.com/mysql-cloud-db-overview/pricing/#Xeround%20FREE).

REASON #1 : Database is stored in the Cloud for Free

REASON #2 : Automatic Backups of the Database

REASON #3 : You can load data over the Internet and retrieve it via mysqldump

REASON #4 : It comes with phpmyadmin (no installation required) to administer and query the database

REASON #5 : You can set up your own access to the data via external SQL tools

- [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
- [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)
- MS Access
- etc.

## Restrictions

1. There are only three storage engines

   - [MyISAM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/myisam/info)
   - [MEMORY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html)
   - [XEROUND](http://xeround.com/main/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Xeround-cloud-database-whitepaper.pdf) (Proprietary Transactional Cloud Storage Engine)
   - Sorry, no InnoDB
2. Maximum Database Size for Free Service is 10MB

Comment: can you show up at the [Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap)?